# Which countries don't have a strong "car culture" (noisy cars & bikes)?

Tags: automobiles, where-on-earth, motorcycles

I currently live in Wales. Like most of the UK, it has a very high rate of people driving extremely loud cars and motorbikes, at all times of the day. Like a lot of people, the noise annoys me, but the police do nothing.
It's like this in many other countries, i.e. Germany.

**So my question is, which countries don't have a high incidence / culture of people driving loud cars, whilst also being relatively well populated**? (whilst Greenland would probably not have this, it's also not a very practical country to live in). Thanks.

Comment: What's your travel question, exactly? You seem to have ruled out Greenland because it's "not a very practical country to live in". If you're trying to decide where to live, that's off topic. If you're trying to find places to visit, what degree (and kind) of "practicality" are you looking for? Is "countries" not likely to be too coarse-grained a distinction here?

Comment: Anti-social people aren't restricted to any one country, and the higher the population, the chances of you encountering them.

Comment: @Cloud That’s a huge generalisation. I’ve lived in several areas of the UK, in cities/towns and in the country, and I would not say that a ‘car culture’ such as you describe is the norm.

Comment: I didn't mention in my previous comment, but I don't recognise it in Germany either, where OP also mentioned. I live on a relatively busy road in a large city and while there's the occasional irritatingly loud car or motorbike, it's maybe a few per week. Certainly not what I'd call "a very high rate .... at all times of the day".

Comment: It also depends on your house and it's location to the road. On one side of my flat I hear the road much louder than on the other side.

Comment: Would this question be a better fit on ExPats? OP mentions "country to live in."

Comment: Many people in Manhattan (part of New York City, New York, USA) do not own or drive cars, but that doesn't make Manhattan a quiet place!

Comment: It's a bit too vague, 'relatively' populated and countries are extreme varied, so it's more by region. We were so pleasantly surprised by the south of Croatia because of the quiet from a lack of cars, the smell and soot!

Comment: Wales does not have a strong "car culture" by world standards. Most of the US has a much more car-oriented society.

Answer (score 3):

Many city centres in Europe restrict cars and other vehicles, with many streets pedestrianised or restricted to buses and other permitted vehicles. Central Oslo has [severely restricted vehicles](https://www.fastcompany.com/90294948/what-happened-when-oslo-decided-to-make-its-downtown-basically-car-free), banning parking and removing traffic from many roads. Central Amsterdam has very little traffic in most areas, with bikes and electric trams providing transport. Copenhagen also has a strong cycling culture and public transport with comparatively few vehicles. Finally, Venice has very few cars.

Comment: And on top of that you can find smaller areas, like islands, which are car free or only allow locals to use cars.

Answer (score 2):

In Russia people there's not much loud cars/bikes and also not customary to blare horn without good reason. The only standing issues is some youth playing their car audio too loud.

You can expect one or two loud cars or bikes per evening I would say.

Walls and windows are usually thick enough so any car sound is non-issue for most of the year when you don't have to keep windows open.

Comment: This is, how it works everywhere, basically. In Germany there's a noisy car or bike every now and then but generally every car is tested every 2 years, if it complies to regulations.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Unfortunately I live in a location where people believe "loud pipes saves lives", and where there is no regular noise testing.  To make it even worse, these people enjoy listening to music from speakers on their bikes - which has to be cranked up  so loud in order to be heard over the top of their already loud exhaust.

Comment: While I am sure you experienced it like this while in Russia, I doubt this is true for the whole of the very big country. (I have not been there but I have seen some things on TV which makes me doubt the whole of the country being quiet all the time.)

Comment: @PeterM Exactly. I would just rather live away from people like that.

Comment: I live in Russia for 35 years and counting, but I have to admit I've not been much to Asian part - maybe in e.g. Vladivostok situation is different but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

I can’t name a country, but perhaps you would like visiting [places with no cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_car-free_places)?

Many of the villages I’ve been in in Spain have streets barely wide enough for one car, and they only appear when someone needs to deliver something.